Can't install Ubuntu 22.04 from usb stick
I'm having a problem starting ubuntu 22.04.4 desktop amd64 from my memory stick. I want to make an Ubuntu/Windows 10 dual boot so I flashed the device with rufus on mbr/legacy bios and changed the boot order in the bios. Then I disconected my mouse, restarted my pc again and i'm welcomed with the grub screen with the options:
try or install ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install
Boot from next volume
UEFI firmware settings

When i chose the first or second option I see the messages:
Error: can't find command 'linux'
Error: can't find command 'initrd'

Also when I switch to the grub command prompt, the ls command doesn't output anything at all.
I have looked up for this problem and some say that is hardware related, my usb sticks work perfectly fine in other devices and I have used them to install windows 10 before. I tried making an installion on a vm with the same usb stick and went perfectly fine. I also tried with multiple usb sticks and they all raise the same problem.
Other than that I haven't found anything really useful. I hope somebody can help me, thank you for reading!
Update: The reason I was having all these problems is because my motherboard is so old that doesn't supports live boot. If you're curious the model is G41T-M7.

Starting from a fresh ISO installed on a USB stick should 'just work'. If you're certain you got the right iso, one guess I would have is maybe you have a bad USB stick.

If the problem is my USB stick shouldn't it raise problems in the VM installation? In any case I'll try with some other USB sitcks and report how it goes.

I suggest you WRITE the ISO (you didn't specify which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product/ISO you're asking about as different installers are available selected at download time) with a simple CLONE mode.  Your choice of write method implies you won't be installing to modern uEFI hardware but 2008 or older boxes (legacy BIOS only).. Is your machine pre-2008 as per your write method?   Also note as you're reformatting ISO during write is your write-software capable of handling 22.04?

@guiverc hey, sorry for the late reply. I'm using rufus to create the installation medium, and my Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 22.04.4 desktop amd64. My machine is old, I checked that it uses MBR/Legacy. Can you explain to me what do you mean with the clone mode? Or at least link to a tutorial? Thank you!

The ISO has capability to boot both ways, so a block for block copy to the USB (clone) will boot both ways, depending upon the machine settings. From Ubuntu, the dd command will do the copy, from windows there used to be (still is?) a "burn image" command from a right click on the iso file from the file manager. That would do the trick, no third party tools needed.

Thank you all for the help! Sadly cloning into the usb wasn't an option for me. I updated the post with the source of the problem.

FYI:  Your motherboard specs mention DDR3 RAM, I still use devices with DDR2 RAM, ie. older devices and they boot current any currently released version of Ubuntu (inc. 24.04 which hasn't been released) but I clone the ISOs to media as per docs. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview  You mention rufus, so check its updated; as older versions can't reformat (as you did) anything newer than 20.04!
